# Heroku worker dyno giving R14 errors - problems with memory management - rmagick memory limit options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, rmagick

I've tried to use a 2X worker dyno, waiting to not get R14 errors, but this is the result:

```
2013-06-04T13:03:30.723260+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=1047M(102.3%)
2013-06-04T13:03:30.723260+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

However, the task for the worker is finished successfully.

Questions:

- How can I decrease the needed memory for my job? - I'm using rmagick gem to convert a list of images to a single multipage pdf.
- How dangerous is to keep the process like this (with R14 errors) as the final job is finishing successfully?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you only running 1 of these jobs at a time in sidekiq? That is, does 1 job take 1 gig of memory?

Comment: It seems like the gem rmagick which I'm also using has memory leaks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958681/how-to-deal-with-memory-leaks-in-rmagick-in-ruby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The problem was with rmagick. It gets all the memory it sees available. It doesn't matter if you use a 2X worker dyno instead of a 1X one. It grows to the maximum available resources. So, [we have to set a limit](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit). But in my case not all the limits worked.

You can make a system call directly this way:

`convert -limit memory 0 -limit map 0 list_of_input_files output_file`

This way, you avoid to use the memory cache, going directly to the disk cache. **This is the only way I've found to avoid R14 errors in heroku**. With other combinations like `-limit memory 32 -limit map 64` or similar, it always gave me errors. I took the idea [from here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=23280&p=97706#p97706).

Of course, you could always use the [rmagick library](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/magick.html#limit_resource) with this lines, however it didn't work for me and I did use the syscall approach explained before:

```
Magick.limit_resource(:memory, 0)
Magick.limit_resource(:map, 0)
```

UPDATE: I've used the `nice` command to ensure more priority. It seems it improves, but eventually I'm getting R14 errors, but it's true they are not so often (even with the same file!).

Comment: I tried it but I can't remember now why I didn't choose it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry but where are you calling this system call from ?

Comment: system() function in ruby :-)

Comment: Simple but efficient ! Thanks !

Comment: Not only rmagick, I guess, but a combination of it and heroku... At last, I had to adapt to heroku specs, that's why I fined rmagick

Comment: Did you manage to eliminate r14 errors eventually? with `-limit memory 0 -limit map 0`

Comment: @NickGinanto Yes, I did, but maybe with the newer stack or with other buildback you can try it again and fine rmagick better.

Answer (score 0):

A little late for the party, but in my case the garbage collector was my savior. Just run `GC.start` after each job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.