# Sidekiq terminated when high memory usage during generating watermark in server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-management, memory-leaks, sidekiq, rmagick

I'm using have a server which running on 4gb ram...

Each uploaded picture will be watermark, so i decided to put in background process. However, when there are a lot of requests of uploading pictures..the server will facing high memory issue, and the memory don't deallocate themselves.

My Questions:
- why sidekiq worker terminate?
- is rmagick memory leak?
- how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided nowhere near the amount of details needed for us to give you informed advice, but I'll try something general: How many Sidekiq workers are you running? Consider reducing the #, then queue up tons of request to simulate a heavy load; keep doing that until you have few enough workers that Sidekiq can comfortably handle the worst load. (Or until you confirm that the issue appears the same even when there's only 1 Sidekiq worker!)

Once you've done that, then you'll have a better feel for the contours of the problem: something that looks like an Rmagick memory leak issue when your server is overloaded, may look different (or give you more ideas on how to address it) when you reduce the workload.

Also take a look at [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958681/how-to-deal-with-memory-leaks-in-rmagick-in-ruby) about Rmagick and memory leaks; it might be worth forcing garbage collection to limit how much damage any given leak can cause.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @topher-hunt..I reduce the into 10 concurrency, and watch the memory, seems like it don't over-used anymore. May i know how to force GC whenever start processing watermark? just do 'GC.start'?

Comment: Hmm, i tried do GC.start before my watermark process, it dont have any effect, the memory still goes up slowly

Comment: I expected that using GC.start *would* help, but either way, at least now you know more specifics about the memory problem. (In my experience they're incredibly easy to misinterpret.) When you say you did `GC.start` at the *beginning* of your watermark process, what about during or at the *end* of the watermark process? Have you tried that?

Comment: I'd read through [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/959473/1729692) and, for that matter, the entire page. It sounds like you might not be able to address the central issue from within Ruby, since the memory leak might be in a process that's *outside* of Ruby.

Comment: hmm, haven't try at the end of the watermark process, but will do...ya, maybe it's outside of Ruby which rmagick used. But I saw doing GC.start is quite heavy process, is that recommend to do it?

Comment: I think it's recommended only if Ruby is creating garbage and you can't easily prevent that. In your case you'll have to try it out and see for yourself how much difference it makes. But there's a decent chance that the memory "garbage" isn't in the Ruby code, rather is in ImageMagick, and in that case `GC.start` probably won't be much help.